# Unable to display expected value in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

i was rounding off the value to .25,.50,.75 and .00 in the javascript. and the code is as below.

```
function roundOff(obj) {
    //alert(document.getElementById("sample").value);
    var val=obj.value;
    var newValue;

    var floorValue = Math.floor(val);
    var remainder = val - floorValue;
    if (remainder < 0.325) {
        if (remainder < 0.125) {
            newValue = floorValue;

        } else {
            newValue = floorValue + 0.25;
        }
    } else {
        if (remainder < 0.625) {
            newValue = floorValue + 0.5;
        } else if (remainder < 0.875) {
            newValue = floorValue + 0.75;
        } else {
            newValue = floorValue + 1;
        }
    }
    alert(floorValue);

        alert(newValue);
        document.getElementById("sample").value=newValue;

    //return obj;
}
```

but am not able to put the value back to the jsp page. if i type 5.5, only 5 is displayed in the jsp. but if i put alert and check the value of floorvalue then it is 5.5. but if i put it to the textbox in jsp it is giving only 5. why is it so???

Comment: Where do you call the function from? It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/y44zz/ (if you'll forgive my use of an inline onblur attribute).

Comment: yes. am calling on keyUp from the textbox. here is the code for tat... <input name="sample" id="sample" type="text" value=""   onkeyup="javascript:roundOff(this);" tabindex="1">

Comment: even in fiddle keyup wont work for after decimal point. any idea how to get that?

Comment: On keyup doesn't make sense, because as you type it'll keep rounding off as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/y44zz/2/ - that is, if you try to enter "5.5" one character at a time, as soon as you type the "." the function removes it again. Programmatically changing the value of the field the user is currently typing in is almost always a bad idea. Do it on blur.

Comment: ok.. checked that wit on blur also. it gives the same effect with the result as i need. thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using onKeyUp in the jsp which was causing the trouble. instead i changed it to onBlur as it was providing the same effect as per my requirement. And thank you  'nnnnnn' for your suggestion. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of your textbox to floorValue, not newValue.

Comment: try retriving it again alert(document.getElementById("sample").value); to see if it's set at all? (at the end)... might be a selection problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using onblur event. because it works fine in fiddle. other than that i see no problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this,

```
document.getElementById("sample").value="+floorValue+";
```

If it works you can Refer Reason [HERE](http://antguider.blogspot.in/2012/06/javascript-tips-and-tricks-part-i.html) fourth Question

Comment: This is completely wrong, and also doesn't seem to have anything to do with the fourth point in the linked blog post which is _also wrong_.